# ¿"Hago lo que me dé la gana" o "Hago lo que me da la gana"?

Tags: coloquialismos, letras-de-canciones

He escuchado los dos: "Hago lo que me dé la gana" y "Hago lo que me da la gana". ¿Cuál es el correcto, o sea, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre los dos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) Hago lo que me dé la gana.

(2) Hago lo que me da la gana.

Las dos oraciones son correctas, pero algo distintas semánticamente.

En (1), la relativa libre "lo que me dé la gana" apunta al futuro y, por lo tanto, entra en el campo de lo posible (de ahí el uso del subjuntivo). La idea es: Hago lo que me venga en gana al momento de hacer algo.

En (2), la relativa libre "lo que me da la gana" apunta al presente: siempre hago lo que me viene en gana.

Si en lugar de "hago" usamos "haré", la idea se ve aún más claramente:

- Haré lo que quiera (en ese momento futuro).
- Haré lo que quiero (lo que quiero ahora).

Answer (score 2):

Aunque he escuchado ambas formas, considero que quizá sería más correcta:

> **Hago lo que me da la gana**

Yo reservaría la otra forma, algo modificada, así:

> **Haré lo que me dé la gana**

En mi opinión, son diferentes, precisamente, por su ámbito temporal. Mientras en el primer caso estamos diciendo algo que pasa (*Hago...*) en el segundo hacemos referencia a algo que aún no ha sucedido, pues pertenece al futuro, que bien podría no llegar a ocurrir (*Haré...).